# Meteor - No login services configured

Tags: meteor, meteorite, meteor-accounts

I am following along with the Discover Meteor book and I am up to the part where we add accounts: I followed along and added the  `accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown` and `accounts-password` packages, but when I click on the dropdown that appears in the navbar I get `No login services configured`. Any ideas where the error might be coming from?

**My code:**

***layout.html***

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    {{> header}}
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
      {{> yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

***header.html***

```
<template name="header">
  <header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="{{pathFor 'postsList'}}">Microscope</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li>{{> loginButtons}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

***packages***

```
meteor-platform
insecure
bootstrap
iron:router
sacha:spin
mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
accounts-password
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 as any mrt package is old and probably no longer maintained

Comment: Seems so,  they should really remove the mrt packages and any reference to meteorite package manager

Comment: I've just checked the book at it does recommend using  ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 . It has been updated quite regularly, so it seem your referring to an old version? Are you accessing it here: https://book.discovermeteor.com/chapter/adding-users ?

Comment: no I downloaded it, I guess the one you linked updates regularly as it is a paid version right?

Comment: Yes. Well worth it as a reference. There are new techniques in there too